# Get Specific class with Jquery/ JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a div containing some html elements. They all have a class named

`class="fileItem read write"`.

But there could be an Element with

`class="fileItem read write selected"`.

Now I want to get this element with the additional 'selected' tag and edit this. Currently I have an in JQuery

```
$(".fileItem").click(function(){
    // Code
});
```

which detect an click on one of these fileItems.

Here I want to edit style tag of the element with 'selected' tag. So is there something where I can say get all by class and select the on with "selected"?

Comment: you need to use `hasClass`

Comment: why not use `$(".fileItem.selected")` - This will **only** be called when class`selected` is present with class `fileItem`.

Answer (score 5):

Just chain the desired class names like you would do in a CSS selector:

```
$(".fileItem.selected").click(function() {
    // do stuff
});'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".fileItem").click(function(){
      $(this).find('.selected').style('blah','blah')
});
```

Something like this will allow you to perform other functions as well as the selected item.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".fileItem").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('.selected').css({
    'color': 'green'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this line of code to get the element with the `selected` class

```
$(".fileItem.read.write.selected").click(function() {
    // code here
});'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
   $(".selected").click(function(){});
```

Comment: Unsafe solution - having some other objects with `.selected` class in DOM we'll affect them.

Comment: If we think it this way then anything in DOM can get affected with any selector :)

Comment: Yes, but `.selected` isn't a name precisely describing nature of the object while `.fileItem` seems to be. There's high probability that some other objects will be `.selected` too.

Comment: Ok, for small projects that doesn't matter, but I think that's just bad practice. Safer solution could be naming the class `.fileItemSelected`, but that's overkill having ability of chaining classes in selectors (`.fileItem.selected`).

Comment: You can also put `html body div#id.class > .fileItem.selected`. The more minimalistic the better.

Answer (score 0):

Use core java script to do this.

```
function func() {
alert("Hello, world!");
}

document.getElementsByClassName("fileItem read write selected")
[0].addEventListener("click", func, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you should be able to combine the two classnames:

```
$(".fileItem.selected").click(function() {
//your actions
});
```